# Is it possible to open a Google Maps POI Infowindow programmatically?

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

Is it possible to open a google maps POI infowindow programmatically, from javascript? As far as I've tried it does not respond to click events to the same coordinates and there doesn't seem to be any API which i can find relating to it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is what you're looking for but as far as i'm aware that kind of functionality is provided by the google places api which can be coupled with the google maps api to display POI on the map and click events that display further information (such as the name of the place as well as ratings and other information if you want it).

Link: https://developers.google.com/places/javascript/